# Show last time WordPress site was updated / modified

Tags: updates

I am trying to display in the header of my WordPress site that last time the site was updated.

The last time being defined as the last time either a post or a page was created / modified / deleted

Anyone have any ideas?  The only examples I can find are all related to a single page.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple query of the `$wpdb->posts` table.

```
$last_update = $wpdb->get_var("
  SELECT post_date 
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
  WHERE post_type IN('post','page') 
  AND post_status = 'publish'
  ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1"
);
var_dump($last_update);
```

You could do the same thing (similar) with ...

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('post','page'),
  'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$last_updated = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($last_updated->post->post_date);
```

... but that may well be overkill just to get the most recent date.

Comment: if you leave out `post_type` won't it search through all types anyway?