# Show last modified date of database

Tags: database, wpdb

Is it possible to get timestamp of last change to database?

The date should reflect **any change** - create, update, delete - and **any table** - posts, comments, post_meta, attachments, etc. I've found some related questions, but all of them target only specific tables, such as [Show last time WordPress site was updated / modified](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131262/show-last-time-wordpress-site-was-updated-modified),

My background: I'm letting my client to fill in their content to the site on my staging environment, while I develop locally. Once in a while I need to synchronize the versions. To see the time of the last modification would ease my worrying, that I accidentally discard their work. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another alternative: hook your local installation to the same database the client is using. That way whatever changes they make, they appear on what you're developing - but you can also touch any files you need to without breaking the staging site as they work on it.

Comment: That's not a bad idea! Not sure if it's possible with my Vagrant powered setup: https://roots.io/trellis/ Will definitely think about it though!

Answer (score 2):

There's an `UPDATE_TIME` column in the `TABLES` table in the `information_schema` database.

So you can try to get the max from that column with e.g.:

```
SELECT MAX(`UPDATE_TIME`) 
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
```

where we replace `'dbname'` with the corresponding database name.

More related info [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated).

From the MySQL 5.7 [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html):

> `UPDATE_TIME` displays a timestamp value for the last `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or
>   `DELETE` performed on `InnoDB` tables that are not partitioned. For MVCC,
>   the timestamp value reflects the `COMMIT` time, which is considered the
>   last update time. Timestamps are not persisted when the server is
>   restarted or when the table is evicted from the InnoDB data dictionary
>   cache.
>
> The `UPDATE_TIME` column also shows this information for partitioned
>   `InnoDB` tables.

There seems to have been a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69689), that `UPDATE_TIME` wasn't updated for InnoDB tables in MySQL <= 5.6, but should be fixed for 5.7+

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I need. `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT UPDATE_TIME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'");` gives me empty result though, do I do someting wrong?

Comment: Did you replace `'dbname'` with the actual db name.?

Comment: Strangely when I test this on my MariaDB test db, I get only non-null UPDATE_TIME  values for my MyISAM tables and only null values for my  InnoDB tables

Comment: I got an error when I tried that, but now I see it was due to missing quotes. Now I'm getting an array of empty objects. 

`Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [UPDATE_TIME] => 
        )
)
// 12 in total`

Comment: I guess you have InnoDB tables and MySQL <= 5.6 ? Seems to have been fixed in 5.7.2 See the bug link.

Comment: This is the version string -  `5.5.5-10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`, so MariaDB and MySQL 5.5.5 I believe. That would answer my question I believe, thank you! I will try to update my provisioning setup and let us know, if that fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Best of luck with that.